# Initializing Hibernate with GWT problem

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, gilead

I'm trying to use Hibernate with GWT (using Gilead) but I got the following error

```
   [WARN] /hibernate/greet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.jaffa.hibernate.server.NewHibernateUtil
    at net.jaffa.hibernate.server.GreetingServiceImpl.<init>(GreetingServiceImpl.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
[ERROR] 500 - POST /hibernate/greet (127.0.0.1) 3632 bytes
   Request headers
      Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12
      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
      Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
      Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
      Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
      Keep-Alive: 115
      Connection: keep-alive
      Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8888/hibernate/hosted.html?hibernate
      X-GWT-Permutation: HostedMode
      X-GWT-Module-Base: http://127.0.0.1:8888/hibernate/
      Content-Type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8
      Content-Length: 175
      Pragma: no-cache
      Cache-Control: no-cache
   Response headers
      Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
      Content-Length: 3632
```

This is still a new project, just I'm trying to do proof of concept.

Thanks
Feras

Comment: What library/jar is net.jaffa.hibernate.server.NewHibernateUtil in? Is this your own class?

Comment: Yes my own hibernate util (I initialize session factory in it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class n.j.h.s.NewHibernateUtil

This error means that the class is found but its initialization failed. Possible causes include

1. some dependencies are unsatisfied ~or~
2. an exception is thrown when executing a static initialization block in the class.

In the particular case of a typical `HibernateUtil` class, I'd bet on the second option. Extract the code of the static initialization block and run it / debug it in a regular `main`, outside the container (and maybe try to improve the error reporting in case of problem).

Comment: Thanks, you are right there was an error in one of the mapping files.

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError means the runtime could not locate the class in its classpath.
It seems you are missing a jar which contains the class net.jaffa.hibernate.server.NewHibernateUtil .

Comment: This is my class and it is in the server package